# I want to send Google Form response to an Email address entered on the form

Tags: google-forms

When a user completes the form to attend a conference. I ask for another email address so their supervisor knows they have signed up and for what date.

How can I use the field on the form as the address to cc the Email to.
the field is "Supervisors Email address"

I would like it to send as soon as they submit the form.